# Show that $S_p=\langle \tau,\sigma \mid \tau^2,\sigma ^p\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

The fact that $$\langle\tau,\sigma \mid \tau^2,\sigma ^p\rangle\ \subset\  S_p$$ is obvious. But how can I show the other inclusion? $p$ is a prime number. The initial question is to show that $S_p$ is generated by a transposition and a $p-$cycle. It looks to be different than $\langle\tau,\sigma \mid \tau^2,\sigma ^p\rangle$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: The group $\langle \sigma, \tau | \tau^2, \sigma^p\rangle = \mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_p$ is infinite, so that's not true. Maybe you actually want to show that $S_p$ is a homomorphic image of the other group? This follows since $(1 2)$ and $(1 2 \cdots p)$ generate $S_p$ and application of the universal property of free groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generators of Symmetric and Alternating Group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317565/generators-of-symmetric-and-alternating-group)

Comment: @NoahOlander: Yes, I want to prove that $S_p$ is generated by a transposition and a $p-$cycle. But it doesn't meant that $S_p=<\tau,\sigma\mid \tau^2,\sigma ^p>$ ? I don't understand... it look to be exactly the same thing to me. If not, why ? And how to show that $S_p$ is generated by a transposition and a p-cycle ?

Comment: @idm See the duplicates on MSE how to generate $S_p$ by an $n$-cycle and a $2$-cycle.

Comment: Notice that in my question, $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: idm, defining a group by generators and relations means that only the relations that follow from the given ones (and group axioms) should hold. If you look at $S_p$, $\sigma=(123\cdots p)$, $\tau=(12)$, then there will be other relations as well. For example $(12)(123\cdots p)=(23\cdots p)$ has order $p-1$. But $(\tau\sigma)^{p-1}=1$ is not a consequence of relations $\tau^2=1=\sigma^p$.

Comment: Defining groups by generators and relations is tricky business. For example [no method exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) for telling whether two elements of the group, given in terms of generators and relations, are equal.

Comment: Ok, I see. So is there a notation to says that it's generated by $\tau$ and $\sigma $ ? Maybe only $S_p=<\tau,\sigma >$ where $\tau$ is a transposition and $\sigma $ a cycle ?

Comment: To answer your original question, if $G\subseteq \mathbf S_n$ contains $\sigma = (1\ 2\ \dots\ n)$ and $\tau = (1\ 2)$, then it contains $\tau^\sigma = (2\ 3)$, $\tau^{\sigma^2} = (3\ 4)$ etc all the way to $(n-1\ n)$. From there, since $(a\ b)^{(b\ c)}=(a\ c)$ its easy to see that $G$ contains all transpositions and then $G$ must be $\mathbf S_n$.

Comment: Is it correct to write $S_p=<t,s>$ where $t$ is a transposition and $s$ a $p-$cycle ? I often see this notation for this, but it is really correct ?

Answer (score 5):

This is false as stated. The group 
$$
G=\langle \tau,\sigma\mid \tau^2=1=\sigma^p\rangle
$$
is always infinite (if $p>1$). It does have $S_p$ as its quotient. There is a surjective homomorphism
$f:G\to S_p, \sigma\mapsto (123\cdots p), \tau\mapsto (12)$.