# Symmetric group isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, group-presentation

> Let $G$ be a group generated by $a$ and $b$ such that order$(a)=2$ and order$(b)=n$. What condition can I impose to $a$ and $b$ to get $G \cong S_n$?

The group $G$ that I'm looking at is a little complicated but I think that is actually isomorphic to $S_n$, so I'm looking for a condition that can prove that.

Comment: See this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/144010/8581) and missed Arturo's answer.