# How to show that two groups makes $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

I need to show that:

1. $S=\left\{(12),(13),...,(1n)\right\}$ generates $S_n$
2. $S=\left\{(12),(123\cdots n)\right\}$ generates $S_n$

How do I show that each one of them generates $S_n$?

Thank you!

Comment: See also this great [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/144010/8581) of missing Arturo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you prove that every element of $S_n$ is equal to a product of transpositions? If so, you just need to show that each of those generating sets contains all transpositions.

Edit: To make this more direct, this task becomes straight forward once you understand how conjugation works in $S_n$.

Comment: This is the first one, how I solved the second?

Comment: Try conjugating $(12)$ by $(123...n)$. The result is

$(123...n)(12)(123...n)^{-1} = (23)$. Depending on how you multiply (from left to right or right to left) this equation may be incorrect. However, this is the general idea.

Comment: Read lemma 2 on page 2 of http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf. This is the general formula for conjugation in $S_n$.

Comment: Yes, but this gives me only the $(ab)$ cycles, no?

Comment: Well, it will actually give $\{(12),(23),...(n-1,n),(n,1)\}$. From this set you can generate all other transpositions. For example $$(23)(12)(23)=(13)$$ and $$(34)(13)(34)=(14).$$